# select() set position

Tags: r

If I have df like this

```
df <- read.table(text="
              id date       paid_at    binded_at  
1            107 2016-12-16 2017-06-02 2017-06-07
2            107 2017-11-27 2017-06-02 2017-06-07
3            107 2017-11-28 2017-06-02 2017-06-07
4            109 2016-11-28 2017-01-01 2017-06-07
5            109 2017-11-29 2017-01-01 2017-06-07
6            110 2017-12-04 2018-01-01 2017-06-07", header=TRUE)
```

How can I easily move paid_at column to 1st place and column id before binded_at column? Im using for that select, but I don't want to write

```
select(paid_at, date, id, binded_at)
```

Because if I have df with dozens of columns, it is complicated.-

Comment: like Len suggests: `df %>% select(paid_at, date, id, everything())` ?

Comment: Hmm yeah seems like I slightly misread the desired order, but our solutions are indeed the same in the sense that you can specify the order for a few columns and then just add `everything()` to keep all other columns in their original order.

Answer (score 5):

```
df %>% 
  select(id, paid_at, everything())
```

You can just select `id` and `paid_at`, and then add `everything()` to select all other columns as well in their original order.

Answer (score 1):

We can hardcode first three columns and then select the remaining ones with `setdiff`.

```
cols <- c("paid_at", "id", "binded_at")
df[c(cols, setdiff(names(df), cols))]

#     paid_at  id  binded_at       date
#1 2017-06-02 107 2017-06-07 2016-12-16
#2 2017-06-02 107 2017-06-07 2017-11-27
#3 2017-06-02 107 2017-06-07 2017-11-28
#4 2017-01-01 109 2017-06-07 2016-11-28
#5 2017-01-01 109 2017-06-07 2017-11-29
#6 2018-01-01 110 2017-06-07 2017-12-04
```

---

With `select` it can be similarly done

```
library(dplyr)
select(df, c(cols, setdiff(names(df), cols)))
```

Comment: I believe `binded_at` is a placeholder for `n` columns to follow. But your solution works anyways.

Comment: @AndreElrico sure. We do not know the exact ordering of columns in OP's actual data but should be possible with some variation.